# I have migrated a .net applicaiton from windows 2003 to 2008, and intermittently "This page can not be diaplayed comes"

Tags: intermittent

I have migrated a .net applicaiton from windows 2003 to 2008, and intermittently "This page can not be diaplayed comes"
If i refresh the page , it starts working fine.
There is no error or warning logged. i have enabled failed tracing request. but There are no logs are getting genearted.
The site works with IE.Is it the issue with IE11?
For me it seems there is nothing related to server error as no event logs.
Please advise.
We have been breaking our head for so long.

Answer (score 1):

the Application pool is being mishandled. check your IIS7 app pool settings and verify DB connections are Being closed.

Comment: What specific IIS setting i should check?